# How to add calendar text box dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to add a calendar text box dynamically on each click on a link. I have tested some codes. For the first declaration it works and not for the others. 
 Here's my code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".hajanDatePicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var intTextBox=0;

        function addElement(){
            var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
            var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','txtDatePicker');
            newTBDiv.innerHTML +="Date:<input id='txtDatePicker' type='text' name='test1'>"; 
            contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="get">
        <div id="content">
            <input type="text" id="txtDatePicker" name="test1"/>
        </div>  
        <p><a href="javascript:addElement();" >Add</a>   
    </form>
</body>
```

When the form loads can get the calender. After clicking "Add" it just opens as a normal text box and not as calendar.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding elements with the same ID. You can switch it to a class name instead, and then use what you currently have (as long as you give it the class `hajanDatePicker`), with the addition of Jakub's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just call

```
$(".hajanDatePicker").datepicker();
```

at the bottom of `addElement` function.

And change

`<input id='txtDatePicker' type='text' name='test1'>`

to

`<input id='txtDatePicker' type='text' class='hajanDatePicker' name='test1'>`

Also, you have multiple inputs on your page with the same id: txtDatePicker.

Comment: Thanks. Just I've added this end of the function. The calender comes but I can't get the date in the text box....

Comment: OH yeah it works great if it's single. I have many input fields such as name, phone, service... I've multiple inputs on the page with the same id: txtDatePicker